# Powershell printer installation script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, printers

I'm trying to create a login script that performs a few actions. I need it to complete the following.

1. Check and record the current default printer.
2. Delete all printers.
3. Install a specific list of printers.
4. Set the default printer back to what the default printer was previously.

I need to do this because we've made some printer name changes on the network and we want to re-map all of the printers with the new names and also install some additional printers. I currently have a batch file calling a .ps1 file. Here's the code from both files.

Login.bat

```
@echo off
powershell -command Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force
Powershell -command " & '\\server\share\MyPSScript.ps1'"
```

Login.ps1

```
# Save current default printer.
Get-WmiObject -Query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true" | foreach {$_.portname} -OutVariable CurDefPrinter

# Deletes all network printers.
Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer | where{$_.Network -eq ‘true‘} | foreach{$_.delete()}

# Maps all network printers.
add-printer -connectionname "\\server\ricoh"
add-printer -connectionname "\\server\hp"

# Set default printer
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "portame='$CurDefPrinter'").SetDefaultPrinter()
```

When I run this, I get this error.

```
C:\Temp\Scripts>Login.bat

C:\Temp\Scripts>REM @echo off
10.0.0.155
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_Printer where portame='10.0.0.155'"
At \\server\share\login.ps1:12 char:2
+ (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "portame='$CurDefPrinter' ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At \\server\share\Login.ps1:12 char:1
+ (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "portame='$CurDefPrinter' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelled PortName wrong so nothing was being returned and you were calling a method on `($null)`

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "portname='$CurDefPrinter'").SetDefaultPrinter()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need to use the Query and Filter option you can do it like this:

```
#to get the current default printer
$default = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | Where-Object {$_.Default -eq "true"}
#to reset the default printer
$default.SetDefaultPrinter()
```

Atleast it works at my enviroment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works for me too, I may use this method.